# write out file / page name in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Lets say I have a URL like this: http://website.com/folder/myfile.asp

How do I make a script that writes out only: "myfile.asp"

Comment: Try using the URL Rewriting tool in IIS
http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/05/31/urlrewrite-module-for-iis7.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Here is the code needed.

```
<%

     Dim arrPath: arrPath = Split(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"), "/")

     Dim fileName: fileName = arrPath(UBound(arrPath))
%>
```

Gets an array of elements in the current scripts URL path and then selects the last element in that array which will be the filename.

Now if you expect to be doing any significant work in a ASP/VBScript I would recommend you spend some time reading *all* the content related to VBScript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Vbscript/default.asp).  There isnt an overwhelming amount of info there but the time spent will pay itself back quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<% = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") %>
```

Comment: No because its dynamic, the script needs to be on every page, generating the filename of the current page :)

Comment: Perhaps your question should be more specific.

Comment: Im sorry but your script above ^^ - writes out: http://mywebsite.com/folder/myfile.asp

I only want it to write out myfile.asp

Comment: You can use split(), which will break the string into an array, then just output the last element of the array.

Comment: How do I do that? - can you change the code above to gain what you are telling you can do? :)

Comment: @user1325927:  Your first comment to this answer needs to be added to your question.  Please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple function for you

```
<%

 Function getFileName(lsPath)

  ' Obtain the virtual file path '
  lsPath = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")

  ' Split the path along the /s. This creates a one-dimensional array '

  arPath = Split(lsPath, "/")

  ' The last item in the array contains the file name '

  GetFileName =arPath(UBound(arPath,1))

 End Function

%>

<%=getFileName(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))%>
```